# How to mock methods using existing objects in java ?

Tags: java, mocking

Is there any way that we can mock certain methods using existing objects ?

I used Power Mock to mock private methods but couldn't find out a way to do the above mentioned task.

Thanks

Comment: Example of using PowerMock is present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9305314/3629114)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to stub out just a method of a real object. If that is the case and if you're using PowerMock with [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) you can check out the 'Spy' feature. You can find [an example here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it would be just override the method in the test case.

```
public class ClassToTest {

    public int someMethod() {
        return 1 + otherMethod();
    }

    protected int otherMethod() {
        return 2;
    }

}

public class ClassToTestTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        ClassToTest classUnderTest = new ClassToTest() {
            @Override
            protected int otherMethod() {
                return 3;
            }
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(4, classUnderTest.someMethod());
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm trying to mock a private method.

Comment: you will not be able to mock a private method... private has the visibility locked to the class that implements it, what you could do is to change the visibility to protected and use the given approach